# Why this code doesn't fit the given problem?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have to calculate the monthly payment of a debt until it reaches 0 and show the progress, payment by payment. The only variable is that if the guy has more money than the debt, it should be done in 1 payment only. Beecrowd keeps telling me it is wrong. Do you see anything I could change? I have tried 10 different ways and this is the last one.

```
ant = int(input())
p = int(input())
dps = 0
pg = 1
if p < ant:
    while dps >= 0:
        pg += 1
        dps = ant - p
        print(f"pagamento: {pg}")
        print(f"antes = {ant}")
        print(f"depois = {dps}")
        print('-' * 5)
        ant = dps
        dps = ant-p
else:
    dps = 0
    print(f"pagamento: {pg}")
    print(f"antes = {ant}")
    print(f"depois = {dps}")
    print('-' * 5)
```

Comment: should interest be included? are all inputs integral or could they be floating-point? should the comparison be `while dps > 0:`?

Comment: All numbers should be positives intereger and it doesn't have interest % or so. This proposed while does not work because I have to print it when it's 0 too

Comment: If *ant* is 100 and *p* is 30, what should the output be?

Comment: 100 would be debt, 30 the monthly payment.

Comment: It should print until it is 0. Now I get it. The example I proposed it goes to 0 perfectly. With 100 as debt, and 30 as monthly payment, it will stop with 10 debt. Now I have to find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly then I suggest:

```
ant = int(input())
p = int(input())

def doprint(pagamento=1, *, antes, depois):
    print(f"pagamento: {pagamento}")
    print(f"antes = {antes}")
    print(f"depois = {depois}")
    print('-' * 5)

if p < ant:
    pg = 1
    dps = 0
    while ant > p:
        ant -= p
        dps += p
        doprint(pagamento=pg, antes=ant, depois=dps)
        pg += 1
else:
    doprint(antes=ant-p, depois=p)
```